# Migrate SharePoint questions from other Stack Exchange sites here?

Tags: support, feature-request

Sharepoint.stackexchange (formerly Sharepointoverflow.com) is out of public beta, and we should be able to move or migrate questions from Stack Overflow or Server Fault, etc. to here, but I don't see that option....?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in missing this point for "belongs on SP", but if you take a look at the bottom of each SE-site you will see that there are many more SE-sites than the five which are clickable. So only for these 5 exists a direct move.

I guess this decision once came from what have been the earliest sites leaving beta status and/ or which one are most useful to offer. Because it is not easy to fit in all non-beta-SE-sites in that form. So I assume you will get a [status-declined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) on that request on SO meta.

I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82104/how-to-migrate-a-question-to-a-se-site-not-on-the-belongs-on-list) on meta where the answer states that you should flag it as needing attention and there write where and why it belongs to. I asked it on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145787/185025) to follow up the discussion (if there start any).

Comment: To be fair, you're more likely to see SP questions on SO than Cycling ones. ;)

Comment: I'll try to rewrite my answer, because that is what I meant. Most questions will have to move from SO to another SE site, but as in picture above visible: there are only 5 SE sites available. And all other like SP are missing.