# Should I copy-paste my answer if I answered the duped question in SO but I feel it belongs to Sharepoint?

Tags: discussion, support

The questions:

- [How to close an infopath form in C# style?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42377/how-to-close-an-infopath-form-in-c-style)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777406/close-infopath-form-with-managed-code

are duplicates.

Initially wrote this as proposal to make possible to flag the questions as dupes between SE sites but then saw the answer to [Migrate SharePoint questions from other Stack Exchange sites here?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/migrate-sharepoint-questions-from-other-stack-exchange-sites-here)

So, I answered the question in SO but, then, saw its dupe in Sharepoint site.

I feel my answer belongs to Sharepoint.
What should or can I do?
To copy-paste my reply?

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past in this situation is to flag the question on SO as 'Other' with a message like this:

> This is a duplicate of this question on SharePoint.SE: (link)
>
> Please could you migrate it there so that it can be merged.

Then, once it has been migrated you can flag it here as a duplicate. Although sometimes the SO mods decide to close or delete the question instead; it's a bit hit-and-miss over there.

Example migrated:

[Can you programmatically add comments to an append-only comment field in a custom item list using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42442/can-you-programmatically-add-comments-to-an-append-only-comment-field-in-a-custo)

[Can you add comments to an append-only field in a list in Sharepoint 2010 using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/can-you-add-comments-to-an-append-only-field-in-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using?lq=1)

Example closed (then deleted by the author):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302063/how-to-convert-infopath-form-created-in-sharepoint-2010-to-word-2010

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is your anwser, I would do it and leave a hint that I answered same question as well as on SO as on SE-SP. If it is someones other answer, I would leave a comment where to find right answer.

But as you see in your specific case now, you cannot answer any longer on SO as it is migrated.

Comment: Umms, I replied into dead-ended (closed) thread