# Can we move questions from Stack Overflow to SharePoint SE

Tags: feature-request, migration

I know this question has been asked a few times, seems last by Mike in 2012..

Since now we are in 2014, is this possible.. It simply annoys me to give Stack Overflow link on SharePoint SE for the users to see a duplicate question :)

Last time asked: 
[Migrate SharePoint questions from other Stack Exchange sites here?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/659/migrate-sharepoint-questions-from-other-stack-exchange-sites-here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should say the answer is still the same; Flag the posts on Stack Overflow and let their moderators take actions to migrate the question.

Comment: Flag the questions on Stack Overflow right ?

Comment: Sorry yes off course :)

Answer (score 3):

As of now we have 5404 questions with no answers. I guess that's more then enough to keep you occupied until Easter...?! :-)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered

## Duplicate on Stackoverflow?

If there is a duplicate you can always cite the SO answer provided that you reference and give correct credit to the answer on SO. Or you write a better answer without reference. Then we have our own instance of the question which we can play the duplicate card on next time the question rises. In the mean time, flag for migration if the question is less than 60 days. Otherwise it's impossible to migrate.

Comment: I understand that, but most of the times we have to post SO's link as answer to some of the Questions.. And we can't mark them as duplicate becoz they don't exist is SPSE.. That is what annoys me !

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Sorry for my blunt post. But you can always cite the SO answer provided that you reference and give correct credit to the answer on SO. Or you write a better answer without reference. Then we have our own instance of the question which we can play the duplicate card on next time the question rises. In the mean time, flag for migration if the question is less than 60 days. Otherwise it's impossible to migrate.

Comment: Okay, no problem.. Thanks :)